# Garbage disposal not working properly

Tags: plumbing

My garbage disposal had a wood corn on the cob stick get stuck in cutter. We got out what we could but now when I put water down in disposal  the water goes into the other side of my sink and won't drain. How do I get this to stop I can't use my dishwasher either the water backs up into the sink. Which seems to have blown my pipes to leak out the water now. The disposal is only 3months old.

Comment: Does the disposer still turn under power? If not, check the circuit breaker reset button on the bottom of the disposer.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a plugged drain which might be in the outlet of the disposer, but most probably is below where the drains join, maybe in the U-trap. Fill both sinks 1/4 full of water and use a plunger first on the non-disposer sink and see if this clears the blockage. If it doesn't, then use the plunger on the disposer side. Push down easy and pull up vigorously on the plunger to pull the plug out and apart, then see if this clears the blockage. Put a stopper in the other drain when you are plunging on one (prevents the suction action of the plunger from just pulling in water through the other drain). The action you want it to pull on the blockage from below.

You may have pieces of wood lodged in the drain. If solid material comes up into the sink, fish it out and put it in the trash.